# Blender file Dialogue window always hides suggested folders, how to show by default?

Tags: interface, file-browser

Whenever I open up the file dialogue, to find an image, install an addon etc... Blender always has my suggested folders hidden, and i have to manually grab pane splitter, dragging down the bottom one to show all the folders.

Is there anyway to manually set this so it DOESNT hide these folders, or always allows, say, 400px of space above?

Heres what it initially gives me:

[image: Hidden suggested folders]

Heres what I want it to be (after i manually drag down the pane)

[image]

I'm on MacOS 10.12.6 running Blender 2.79

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have tested this on Windows but I hope it works on Mac as well.

### To modify Open File dialog settings, you need open new Blend, set the dialog panels to desired positions and **save the current Blend as a *Startup File***:

1. Start the Blender so you have empty (default) project opened
2. Open the *Open File* dialog by *File* > *Open* (or <kbd>F1</kbd>)
3. Resize your panels as you wish
4. Close the dialog so you return to Blender's workspace
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to *Save Startup File* - this saves the current settings as a default for any new projects (together with *your* panel)

   (*this trick also works for remembering startup window configuration for multiple displays*)

Note: If you want to use <kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut for opening a file, you need to configure this dialog as well, it's settings is independent from *File -> Open* dialog.

**To save settings of the *Install Add-on*** dialog, don't open the dialog from *User Preferences*, but use <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> & type "Install" > hit *Install Add-on from File*. It will use *Open File* dialog settings this way.

Comment: That should work on Mac just fine—haven't tried it, but it works for other settings, like screen layouts.

Comment: works for file open dialogues for blender scenes, but when I install an addon, I open up settings-->Add-ons -->Install Add-on-from-file --(resize)--(close addon dialogue)---(reopen)... Changes saved Yes! But when i Reopen settings-->(Add-ons)--> Install add-on-from-file..... The resize is not saved...  Its as if it only saves it on the spawned UI settings window object.

Comment: I have updated the answer for a workaround, that could work for you.

Comment: Perfect! Happy blending :)